# Do these cracks in a brick wall indicate foundation movement?

Tags: structural, brick, construction, crack, mortar

This is the back wall of my detached single garage. It's just single skin, built in the 60s and as I want to use this building as a workshop, I'm looking to spend a bit of money getting it properly insulated inside. My question is should I be worried about these cracks? Is it a sign of foundation movement? I don't want to spend money upgrading the garage to then have it be unstable and need re-building in the near future.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it safe to presume that the garage is built out of wood and has the brick as an exterior siding? Or does the garage wall consist solely of this single layer of bricks? i.e. when you look at the inside, what do you see?

Comment: Are there similar cracks on the inside?

Comment: @FreeMan - The walls are just a single layer of brick only. The corners are double skinned.  The only wood in the structure is a couple of beams and rafters that form the roof.

Comment: @LeeSam - Yes I believe those cracks go through to the inside too however the previous owner looks to have siliconed the gaps and painted over ( I assume to block draughts)

Comment: I'm always flabbergasted at how a single row of bricks can be considered a proper wall. There's so little lateral stability in brick in this narrow configuration that it's almost guaranteed to fail. Are you _sure_ that's all there is to the wall? Are you sure it's not a _double_ course wall? Can you actually see daylight through those cracks?

Comment: @isherwood - Yes I am 100% sure. I replaced a few blown out bricks myself and can assure you it's just one brick thick. When we bought the property our surveyor said that in their experience it's quite common to find garages constructed from single-brick - especially ones that were built 60 years ago as outbuildings weren't built to the same standards as houses. The only places where the wall is double skinned is at the corners and the 2 brick piers on the side wall that sit either side of the personnel door.

Comment: In that case I think I'd be looking at options for a stabilizing retrofit of posts after I'd determined that the foundation was stable. You can probably fasten a few members to the wall at intervals and dramatically increase its stability so that a bump with a car doesn't bring the whole thing down.

Answer (score 2):

If the wall is constructed of brick, as opposed to the brick being a façade, then yes, you have foundation movement. Whether it's *still* moving, and whether it's something that needs to be addressed urgently is anyone's guess with the little information we have. You'll need to investigate the foundation situation to learn more.

Comment: and "investigate the foundation situation" will probably require a skilled professional being on site.

Comment: Meh. Anyone can dig a hole and see if it's woefully inadequate with a little research.

Comment: @isherwood - true, I can tell if something is woefully inadequate, but I'm sure I can't determine that it is perfectly fit for long-term use. The professional can.

Comment: i feel like i could kick a 60 year old wall like that and get that kind of damage - often 60 years and mortar mean you can carve it out with your finger.  brick walls typically have brick ties that tie into structure.  this thing was built by the smartest of the little pigs in a few hours.  I can't imagine that they find the foundation meets modern code given the wall doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the crack was caused by the movement of the support. You can examine the foundation by digging or opening up the interior (wood frame) wall to check the sill plate, which will not be in full contact with the foundation if it has settled.

Comment: that would be true if there was a stud wall on the inside...  it sounds like the interior wall is paint on the interior face of this single course of brick.